# Why have column borders gone missing in Rhythmbox gui?

Tags: themes, gui, rhythmbox

My theme doesn't use shading, only borders and outlines.

Since a few weeks ago, Rhythmbox has stopped drawing all borders so that I can't see columns or sections very well. Even my scrollbars are not being drawn correctly.

This makes the GUI really hard to use. When I change themes it seems that Rhythmbox has changed its GUI to use only shading to delineate sections, tabs, columns, etc.. Rhythmbox seems to be the only program that has this problem so I'm guessing this is a Rhythmbox thing, but not sure. My theme is not updated for GTK 3.6.

Maybe that is the issue? Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: a screen shout would be most useful.

Comment: Sorry, can't figure out how to post a screenshot within these comments. Before: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/547/beforev.png/ and after: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/211/afterc.png/.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is a problem with the current version of Rhythmbox Tray Icon (Mendhak version). Disabling this plugin and restarting Rhythmbox made the theme display correctly again. Switched to Rhythmtray instead. No problems with the theme with this plugin.